# How can I make a screen reader read out a mix of text and components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, accessibility

I have the following array:

```
const row = ['I agree to the', {}, 'and', {}];
```

Where the 2 objects are React components that make the text a link.

I then render this text like this:

```
<WrapperComponent>
    {row}
</WrapperComponent>
```

I get the following sentence rendered:

> I agree to the Terms of Service and Privacy Policy

And if I turn on the screen reader, the whole sentence gets focused and read out.

My question is whether I can do something to make the screen reader read the whole sentence first, and then have the first link element "Terms of Service" focused if the user swipes right once, and "Privacy Policy" if he swipes right twice.

Comment: Could you post the actual HTML code produced and/or an example page ? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems confusing for the user.

Comment: I would suggest another title for the question: ”How to make a screen reader read interactive child elements of an interactive element”. What do you think, @Bobimaru?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class for those if you want them to be programmatically focused
this class will use Refs in DOM Elements

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.component= React.createRef();
    }
    render() {
        return <div ref={this.component} />;
    }
    focushere(){
        this.component.current.focus();
    }
}
```

so you can add an eventlistener based on user's swipe gesture so you can just access the class and call the `focushere()` function

Comment: If I well understand, your solution won't work. When the screen reader is active, sweep gestures are absorbed by the screen reader in order to do its work and your JS code won't ever catch them.

Answer (score 0):

The following causes the entire checkbox sentence to be read first, then a swipe right says "terms of service".  However, the next swipe right says "and" and then the next swipe right says "privacy policy", at least on ios.  I don't have an android device to test it on.  So that's close to what you want.  If your two components are links, they should cause the swipe to move to them.

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  i agree to the <a href="#">terms of service</a> and <a href="#">privacy policy</a>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

We are assuming that your `<WrapperComponent>` is a labelled checkbox, hence another interactive element which can receive focus.

[MDN discourages using interactive elements inside labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#interactive_content):

> Don't place interactive elements such as anchors or buttons inside a label. Doing so makes it difficult for people to activate the form input associated with the label.

So, while it might work in some screen readers/browsers, you should avoid it.

MDN further suggests the following solution (adjusted to your text):

```html
<label for="tac">
  <input id="tac" type="checkbox" name="terms-and-conditions">
  I agree to the Terms of Service and Privacy Policy
</label>
<p>
  Read our 
  <a href="terms-of-service.html">Terms of Service</a>
  and our
  <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
</p>
```